# Cast instance of generic type to "template" instance

Tags: c#, generics, casting

This might be a silly question and I don't really need this for anything but I was just curious...

The best way to describe it is using a example so here it is:

```
using System;

namespace GenericExample
{
    public interface IFoo { }

    public interface IFoo2 { }

    public class Foo1: IFoo , IFoo2 { }

    public class Foo2 : IFoo, IFoo2 { }

    public class MyGeneric<T> where T : IFoo , IFoo2, new() { }

    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyGeneric<Foo1> obj1 = new MyGeneric<Foo1>();
            MyMethod(obj1);//I can treat obj1 as MyGeneric<T> in MyMethod

            MyGeneric<Foo2> obj2 = new MyGeneric<Foo2>();

           //But can I use is as MyGeneric<T> in this method???
           //MyGeneric<?> obj3 = null;
           //obj3 = (MyGeneric<?>)obj1; 
           //obj3 = (MyGeneric<?>)obj2; 
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void MyMethod<T>(MyGeneric<T> arg) where T : IFoo, IFoo2, new() 
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I don't think it is possible to treat obj1 as MyGeneric< T> in Main
 but at the same time it feels strange since I can pass it as a MyGeneric< T> argument

Comment: What do you mean by "treat obj1 as MyGeneric< T>", what do you wish to do with `obj1` in `Main`?

Comment: @YacoubMassad I updated the example.Imagine T implements an interface (or more) .Could I create a variable of MyGeneric<"T"> and point s to any of the concrete implementations? Again ,I don't need this I was curious if there was I way to make this compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot cast it to `MyGeneric<T>` in `Main` because in the scope of `Main` there is no such type as `T`. Actually it's not really clear what you mean by

> to treat obj1 as MyGeneric< T> in Main

When passing `obj1` to `MyMethod` you don't "treat it as `MyGeneric<T>`". It is the compiler which *infers the type of `T`* for you. It knows that `T` is `Foo1` here and translates your call

```
MyMethod(obj1);
```

to

```
MyMethod<Foo1>(obj1);
```

So the type of the parameter `arg` inside of `MyMethod` will at *runtime* also be `MyObject<Foo1>`, not an unspecified `MyObject<T>`.

Comment: That's what I thought,I was just wondering if I could abuse the language/compiler to make this work

Answer (score 1):

There is no common base-type for MyGeneric and MyGeneric, so I assume the answer is no. In contrast to Java generics in C# are strongly typed types and not just placeholders, so they don´t have anything in common - except a name. However actually they are different types, think of them as just `MyGeneric<T1>` being a type `Foo` and `MyGeneric<T2>` being `Bar`.

A way around this is to define a non-generic version of your generic class:

```
public class Foo1 { }
public class MyNonGeneric { }
public class MyGeneric<T> : MyNonGeneric where T : new() { }
```

Comment: Thanks HimBromBeere but I don't need a way around this,I don't really need this code